# i cant mapp the Texture to the plane that i made in java3d ( SimpleUniverse)

Tags: java, textures, loader

hello guys i would be very thankful for help with my code. i just made a main menu for my first game in Java3d (VirtualUniverse). So my problem that i cant solve is that i trying to mapping an texture on the plane that i made and its not work. the texture not appear it just coloring the plane with the texture pixels but nothing more. im trying to load the image in line 78 of the backGround class... i have here 3 classe 1) backGround is the main class that renders all. 2)plane class here i make a plane. 3) Menutexts class here i made the words.

1) backGround class:

```
package Aplication;

import com.sun.j3d.utils.universe.SimpleUniverse;

import java.applet.Applet;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Frame;
import java.awt.GraphicsConfiguration;

import javax.media.j3d.AmbientLight;
import javax.media.j3d.Appearance;
import javax.media.j3d.Background;
import javax.media.j3d.BoundingSphere;
import javax.media.j3d.BranchGroup;
import javax.media.j3d.Canvas3D;
import javax.media.j3d.DirectionalLight;
import javax.media.j3d.ImageComponent2D;
import javax.media.j3d.Shape3D;
import javax.media.j3d.Texture;
import javax.media.j3d.TextureAttributes;
import javax.media.j3d.TransformGroup;
import javax.vecmath.Point3d;
import javax.vecmath.Vector3f;

import com.sun.j3d.utils.applet.MainFrame;
import com.sun.j3d.utils.image.TextureLoader;
import com.sun.j3d.utils.universe.SimpleUniverse;

public class backGround extends Applet{
    private java.net.URL bgImage = null;

    public backGround(){
        init();
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        GraphicsConfiguration config =
                SimpleUniverse.getPreferredConfiguration();

        Canvas3D c = new Canvas3D(config);
        add("Center", c);

        SimpleUniverse u = new SimpleUniverse(c);

        //set background Texture
        u.addBranchGraph( createBackground() );

        BranchGroup scene = createSceneGraphMenu();

        // This will move the ViewPlatform back a bit so the
        // objects in the scene can be viewed.
        u.getViewingPlatform().setNominalViewingTransform();
        scene.compile();

        u.addBranchGraph(scene);

    }
    public void init(){
        setSize(1280,650);

    }
    // create the BackGround
    public BranchGroup createBackground(){
        BranchGroup bg = new BranchGroup();
        ImageComponent2D image = new TextureLoader(
                 "C:/Users/bounty_wiz/workspace/finalProject/images/sky.jpg", this).getScaledImage( 1300,750 );

        Background background = new Background(image);
        background.setApplicationBounds(new BoundingSphere(new Point3d(0,0,0), 1000));
        bg.addChild(background);
        return bg;
    }

    // create the main menu
    public BranchGroup createSceneGraphMenu(){
        BranchGroup menu = new BranchGroup();

        // Load Texture
        Texture tex = new TextureLoader( "C:/Users/bounty_wiz/workspace/finalProject/images/grass.jpg", this ).getTexture( );
        Appearance appear = new Appearance(); // appearance to configure the texture
        Shape3D planee = new plane(appear).getShape(); // create plane ( constructor of plane class)
        appear.setTexture(tex); 
        planee.setBounds(new BoundingSphere());
        menu.addChild(planee);

        // set ambient light
        AmbientLight lightA = new AmbientLight();
        lightA.setInfluencingBounds(new BoundingSphere());
        menu.addChild(lightA);

        //set Directional light
        DirectionalLight lightD1 = new DirectionalLight();
        lightD1.setInfluencingBounds(new BoundingSphere());
        Vector3f direction = new Vector3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);
        direction.normalize();
        lightD1.setDirection(direction);
        menu.addChild(lightD1);

        // make texts
        TransformGroup trans = new Menutexts().getTrans();
        menu.addChild(trans);

        return menu;
    }




public static void main(String argv[]) {
    Frame frame = new MainFrame(new backGround(), 750, 750);
  }
}
```

/* ==== 2) plane class =============================*/

```
package Aplication;

import java.awt.Frame;

import javax.media.j3d.Appearance;
import javax.media.j3d.Geometry;
import javax.media.j3d.GeometryArray;
import javax.media.j3d.Material;
import javax.media.j3d.QuadArray;
import javax.media.j3d.Shape3D;
import javax.media.j3d.Texture;
import javax.vecmath.Color3f;
import javax.vecmath.Point3f;
import javax.vecmath.Vector3f;

import com.sun.j3d.utils.image.TextureLoader;

public class plane extends Shape3D {
    private Shape3D plane = new Shape3D();

    public plane(Appearance app){
        plane.setGeometry(createGeometry(new Point3f(-1.5f, -0.5f, -5.0f), new Point3f(-1.5f, -0.5f, 1.0f),new Point3f(1.5f, -0.5f, 1.0f), new Point3f(1.5f, -0.5f, -5.0f)));
        plane.setAppearance(createAppearance(app));
    }

    private Geometry createGeometry(Point3f A, Point3f B, Point3f C, Point3f D){
          QuadArray plane = new QuadArray(4, GeometryArray.COORDINATES
                  | GeometryArray.NORMALS);
          plane.setCoordinate(0, A);
          plane.setCoordinate(1, B);
          plane.setCoordinate(2, C);
          plane.setCoordinate(3, D);

          Vector3f a = new Vector3f(A.x - B.x, A.y - B.y, A.z - B.z);
          Vector3f b = new Vector3f(C.x - B.x, C.y - B.y, C.z - B.z);
          Vector3f n = new Vector3f();
          n.cross(b, a);

          n.normalize();

          plane.setNormal(0, n);
          plane.setNormal(1, n);
          plane.setNormal(2, n);
          plane.setNormal(3, n);

          return plane;
    }

    private Appearance createAppearance(Appearance app){
          Color3f color = new Color3f(0.0f,1.5f,0.0f);
          Material material = new Material();
          material.setDiffuseColor(color);
          app.setMaterial(material);

          return app;
    }

    public Shape3D getShape(){
        return plane;
    }
}
```

/*======= 3) Menutexts class ============================*/

```
package Aplication;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;

import javax.media.j3d.AmbientLight;
import javax.media.j3d.Appearance;
import javax.media.j3d.BoundingSphere;
import javax.media.j3d.DirectionalLight;
import javax.media.j3d.Font3D;
import javax.media.j3d.FontExtrusion;
import javax.media.j3d.Material;
import javax.media.j3d.Shape3D;
import javax.media.j3d.Text3D;
import javax.media.j3d.Transform3D;
import javax.media.j3d.TransformGroup;
import javax.vecmath.Color3f;
import javax.vecmath.Point3f;
import javax.vecmath.Vector3f;

public class Menutexts {
    private String fontName = "TestFont";
    private String singlePlayer = null;
    private String multiPlayer = null;
    private String instructions = null;
    TransformGroup objScale;

    public Menutexts(){
        singlePlayer  = "Single Player";
        multiPlayer = "MultiPlayer";
        instructions = "Instructions";
        objScale = new TransformGroup();

        Transform3D t3d = new Transform3D();
        // Assuming uniform size chars, set scale to fit string in view
        t3d.setScale(1.5/16);
        objScale.setTransform(t3d);

        // identity.  Enable the TRANSFORM_WRITE capability so that
        // our behavior code can modify it at runtime.  Add it to the
        // root of the subgraph.
        TransformGroup objTrans = new TransformGroup();
        objTrans.setCapability(TransformGroup.ALLOW_TRANSFORM_WRITE);
        objTrans.setCapability(TransformGroup.ALLOW_TRANSFORM_READ);
        objScale.addChild(objTrans);

        Font3D f3d;

        f3d = new Font3D(new Font(fontName, Font.ITALIC, 1),
                 new FontExtrusion());
        Text3D txt1 = new Text3D(f3d, singlePlayer, new Point3f( -2.2f, 1f, -1.f));
        Text3D txt2 = new Text3D(f3d, multiPlayer, new Point3f( -2.2f, -0.3f, -1.f));
        Text3D txt3 = new Text3D(f3d, instructions, new Point3f( -2.2f, -1.4f, -1.f));
            Shape3D shape1 = new Shape3D();
            Shape3D shape2 = new Shape3D();
            Shape3D shape3 = new Shape3D();
            Appearance app = new Appearance();
            Material shapeMaterial = new Material();
            shapeMaterial.setLightingEnable(true);
            shapeMaterial.setDiffuseColor(new Color3f(1,1,0));
            app.setMaterial(shapeMaterial);

            shape1.setGeometry(txt1);
            shape1.setAppearance(app);

            shape2.setGeometry(txt2);
            shape2.setAppearance(app);

            shape3.setGeometry(txt3);
            shape3.setAppearance(app);

            // set Lightning
            Color3f ambientColor = new Color3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
            AmbientLight ambientLightNode = new AmbientLight(ambientColor);
            ambientLightNode.setInfluencingBounds(new BoundingSphere());
            objTrans.addChild(ambientLightNode);

            // Set up the directional lights
            Color3f light1Color = new Color3f(0.862f, 0.862f, 0.862f);
            Vector3f light1Direction  = new Vector3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);

            DirectionalLight light1
                = new DirectionalLight(light1Color, light1Direction);
            light1.setInfluencingBounds(new BoundingSphere());
            objTrans.addChild(light1);          

            objTrans.addChild(shape1);
            objTrans.addChild(shape2);
            objTrans.addChild(shape3);
    }

    public TransformGroup getTrans(){
        return objScale;
    }
}
```